# Permission Issue of Document Set in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, document-library, permissions

Here is the permission settings of my user:

- Site: Limited access
- Library: Limited access
- Document Set (inside library): Full Control.

**Issue**: When accessing directly the document library, the user is unable to upload documents in the document library. He can see the documents but all the controls are disabled. Now If I give 'Read/View Only' permission at sub-site level, he is able to upload documents in the document set.

'Read/View Only' permission at site or library level is not an ideal solution for me.

What am I missing? 
Why unique permission is not working?

Below is the image of my site page library. There is no document set interface page in it
[image]

Comment: Just go to check permission in site settings and check the permissions of the users. i think some other permission is conflicting with your permissions

Comment: no where it is conflicting..We have already checked the settings. the permissions are as it is mentioned in my question

Comment: I deleted my answer because I created this scenario on my Test farm and got the results you expected.  I cannot duplicate your issue.

Comment: Can you check to see if someone added permissions to the permission level of "View Only/Read Only"? Also why do you have Full Control for the document set whenever you don't want them to upload? Not sure I understood that.

Comment: No the permission level of View Read only is intact..it is the same what SharePoint provides.
I am setting unique permission to a document set.. only selected users can have full control over that document set.

Comment: You may need to create a new permission level to allow the "Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container"  or another Site permission. I think that's what's wrong here.

Comment: That is already been selected in all the permission levels available. I don't know how creating a new one will change the settings

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I create a custom permission level.

In this custom permission level I only checked the following under "Site permissions":

1.Use Remote Interfaces  -  Use SOAP, Web DAV, the Client Object Model or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site.

2.Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container.

I set this custom permission level to my desired group.  Afterwards, the group could access and open office documents in the library/document set, however they couldn't browse the site.